# How to works secure keyboard software?

Tags: logging, keyboard

Secure keyboard softwares are kind of programs which offer protection against keyloggers. I know it.

But, how do these softwares protect computer users?

Answer (score 0):

The soft ware version I know encrypts the stuff you type.
That will not defend against hardware loggers in public cafes.  So the second solution is to have a virtual keyboard on the screen where you click with mouse or touch screen .